# If request in mysql where statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a list of my blog entries, they are all in english language but some are in spain... to get it correctly in spain I use following sql statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM blog_items 
JOIN blog_items_trans on blog_items.id = blog_items_trans.element_id 
WHERE blog_items.parent_id = 0 
AND blog_items_trans.language = 'es'
```

I thing there is to implement around of `blog_items_trans.language = 'es'`

What I tried is after `AND` to add: `blog_items_trans.language = 'es' OR blog_items_trans.language = 'en'` but so I get all element from both langauges.

How can I check there if a element don't exist in spain then get it in english?

Comment: Why use a WHERE clause of language in the first place? The table have both Spain and English and since you want both language (JOIN), you can just drop the language clause and just return all transaction with parent_id = 0.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are combining an `OR` clause with a `WHERE` clause. Without brackets, the `OR` clause doesn't correspond specifically to the `AND` clause, but rather **everything** that precedes it. That is to say, your initial code will attempt grab any row that is **both** in Spanish and has no parent, **OR** in English (with the possibility of not having a parent).

Without brackets, this would be equivalent to:

```
SELECT * 
FROM blog_items 
JOIN blog_items_trans on blog_items.id = blog_items_trans.element_id 
WHERE (blog_items.parent_id = 0 AND blog_items_trans.language) = 'es'
OR blog_items_trans.language = 'en'
```

To ensure that you only grab rows with no parents that are **either** in English or Spanish, simply add brackets inside of your `AND` statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM blog_items 
JOIN blog_items_trans on blog_items.id = blog_items_trans.element_id 
WHERE blog_items.parent_id = 0 
AND (blog_items_trans.language = 'es' OR blog_items_trans.language = 'en')
```

Hope this helps! :)